# (internal error) Ngnix + uwsgi +django : no module named django

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, virtualenv, uwsgi

So im trying to deploy a django app with nginx and uwsgi , ngnix is running well and the django app is working well with manage.py runserver , but when i try to deploy it with uwsgi it said Internal Server Error , and when i check my uwsgi logs that what i get (No module named django)
[image]

the virtualenv python version is 3.6.9 ,i'dont know if this error is caused because of imcompatibilty with python version of virtual environement and the Uwsgi one or just because i missed somethings , my uwsgi specs are
[image]

this is my uwsgi ini file :

```
[uwsgi]
vhost = true
plugins = python
socket = /tmp/mainsock
master = true
enable-threads = true
processes = 4
wsgi-file = /var/www/PTapp-launch/ptapp/wsgi.py
virtualenv = /var/www/venv/site
chdir = /var/www/PTapp-launch
touch-reload = /var/www/PTapp-launch/reload
env = DJANGO_ENV=production
env = DATABASE_NAME=personal_trainer
env = DATABASE_USER=postgres
env = DATABASE_PASSWORD=********
env = DATABASE_HOST=localhost
env = DATABASE_PORT=5432
env = ALLOWED_HOSTS=141.***.***.***
```

Answer (score 0):

i have finally found the problem , when i was running manage.py runserver i had to use sudo , but when i didnt it was throwing the same error , (no module named Django) , so what i did its i uninstall all requirements and then use super user to create new virtual environnement and link it in uwsgi.ini, i also restart both of nginx and uwsgi, so everything work fine now ...